# Whitespace at the bottom of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a "sketchpad" mini-project. Most features are working so far, but I'm having one issue. The sketchpad uses a 16x16 grid by default. When I fill in the bottom row of the grid, you can still see a tiny white line. I have no idea where it could be coming from.

This is an image of the issue I mentioned above

[image: White line under grid]

Here is the code: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/agrullon95/L2ykotem/)

```
#grid {
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: We don't have idea also if you don't post any code: jsfiddle.net

Comment: Honestly I can't even find the tiny white line. Maybe is very very tiny

Comment: @LOTUSMS I think he say after the colored blocks.

Comment: Without seeing your source, it is impossible to assist you. I suspect it is a simple fix, but please post all applicable code (JS, HTML, and CSS) to a jsfiddle so that we can review it.

Comment: Well, in that case, is not tiny at all! Either way, this is a closed question until code is provided

Comment: Remove the height on your grid or change it to 448px.

Comment: WOW thank you! I removed the height. I don't understand why that worked, but it works perfectly now.